# What operating systems allow ssh connection on first boot (with no configuration)?

Tags: ssh, sd-card, wireless, operating-systems

So let's say I don't have a monitor and keyboard handy to hook my pi up to? What images are available to put on the SD card so that I can connect to ssh on first boot up? Do most operating system images do that? (I know NOOBs doesn't, but it's just an installer.)

I do have ethernet available (although answers that work when only wifi is available would be nice too).

Comment: I believe recent versions of Raspbian do.

Comment: How do you expect WIFI to work? You'll need to specify the SSID and the WPA key before the connection could be established.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev See [Ghanima's answer](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/39152/24499).

Comment: I haven't tried "most operating system". What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

It's not an image which you can run directly, but an installer, but it does have an ssh server running by default: https://github.com/debian-pi/raspbian-ua-netinst
It is quite minimal though (no X etc), so you'll have to install all the packages you want yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Literally not an answer yet technically it still is ;)

**Arch linux**. Both the version for the [Pi (ARMv6)](http://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv6/raspberry-pi) and the [Pi2 (ARMv7)](http://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv7/broadcom/raspberry-pi-2) have `sshd` up and running after installation. `dhcp` is also running providing connectivity when attached to a router via ethernet.

Thing is that Arch does not provide images anymore, but a tar.gz'ed root filesystem. Following the linked installation procedures however will produce an operational system on the SD card.

*Skip this part if insisting on "with no configuration", in that case no WiFi though*: Since installation requires the SD card to be mounted on another running system, credentials for WiFi access or network configuration could be saved at the appropriate files.

Comment: Could you include instructions on how to add the wifi credentials to the root filesystem.

Comment: I don't run my Pi on WiFi, so I did not do it. I would have to read that up too (with no own real life experience). If possible I'd leave the issue to somebody else.

Comment: Oh, and by no configuration, I meant configuration with a monitor.